# What kernel services does Python depend upon?

Tags: python, embedded

Despite not being recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519346/porting-python-to-an-embedded-system) to port Python without an OS, this is still an option I am considering.

What would be the complete list of kernel services the most minimal version Python would need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Porting Python to an embedded system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519346/porting-python-to-an-embedded-system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the *absolute very least*, you would need some sort of [VFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) so that `os` and various parts of `sys` can work.